# why would react not render conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have an issue while trying to render this list, item.cars, item.yachts and item.villas are numbers, what could be the reason for this not showing absolutely anything?

```
const renderItems = (locations) => {
<div className={styles.list}>
  {locations.map((item) => {
    if (item.cars != 0 || item.yachts != 0 || item.villas != 0)
      return (
        <DestinationItem
          id={item.id}
          image={Image[item.id]}
          name={item.name}
          subtitle={item.description}
          description={DESTINATIONS_DESCRIPTION[item.id]}
        />
      );
    return null;
  })}
</div>;
};
```

this is an item in locations object

```
cars: 0
description: "(Miami, Palm Beach, Broward)"
id: 3
name: "South Florida"
photo: "http://l.amazonaws.com/areaphotos/Audi_R8_a.jpg"
villas: 69
yachts: 53
__proto__: Object
```

this is the whole component code:

```
const Destinations = locations => {
 const renderItems = (locations) => {
  <div className={styles.list}>
  {locations.map(
    (item) =>
      (item.cars != 0 || item.yachts != 0 || item.villas != 0) && (
        <DestinationItem
          id={item.id}
          key={item.id}
          image={Image[item.id]}
          name={item.name}
          subtitle={item.description}
          description={DESTINATIONS_DESCRIPTION[item.id]}
        />
      )
  )}
</div>;

console.log(locations, 'data');
return (
  <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
    <div className={styles.title}>
      <h1>Pick Your Destination</h1>
        </div>
        {renderItems(locations)}
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default Destinations;
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the rest of the component :) It's hard to guess without knowing what `locations` is or what the data looks like.

Comment: https://sun9-2.userapi.com/c858136/v858136776/1f56a0/I4KvBVwe5v4.jpg that's what item in locations looks like

Comment: You can edit your question to include that as code :)

Comment: thanks, never posted a question before, so im new to this thing :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to take a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) - the section on [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) is especially useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Destinations` component takes `locations` as a prop, correct? In that case, you'll want to either [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the props object, like this:

```
const Destinations = ({ locations }) => {
```

or this

```
const Destinations = props => {
  const { locations } = props
```

or just use the props object and access the fields separately:

```
const Destinations = props => {
  // ...
  return (
    // ...
    {renderItems(props.locations)}
    // ...
  )
}
```

Additionally, the `renderItems` function has curly braces around it, so you need to use `return` to return a value from it. It's currently returning `undefined`, as there is no `return`.

```
const renderItems = (locations) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.list}>
      {locations.map((item) => {
        if (item.cars !== 0 || item.yachts !== 0 || item.villas !== 0)
          return (
            <DestinationItem
              id={item.id}
              image={Image[item.id]}
              name={item.name}
              subtitle={item.description}
              description={DESTINATIONS_DESCRIPTION[item.id]}
            />
          );
        return null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or you can use the [concise form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) of an arrow function, and replace the curly braces with parentheses:

```
const renderItems = (locations) => (
  <div className={styles.list}>
    {locations.map((item) => {
      if (item.cars !== 0 || item.yachts !== 0 || item.villas !== 0)
        return (
          <DestinationItem
            id={item.id}
            image={Image[item.id]}
            name={item.name}
            subtitle={item.description}
            description={DESTINATIONS_DESCRIPTION[item.id]}
          />
        );
      return null;
    })}
  </div>
);
```

As a side-note, you'll almost always want to use strict equality operators (`===` and `!==`) instead of abstract equality operators (`==` and `!=`). The latter one has its [share of pitfalls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness), e.g. `'1' == 1` is true, as [unexpected things](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) like `[[]] == 0`!

Comment: somehow it still renders all of items, even where ```item.cars``` or ```item.yachts``` or ```item.villas``` equals to 0

Comment: @DannyLyzo What is the expected behavior? The current logic renders if **either of** `cars`, `yachts`, or `villas` is *not zero*.

Comment: @DannyLyzo I also edited by answer to address an issue with the component's props.

Comment: the expected behavior is that when all three of cars, yachts and villas have 0, the element wont render, when one of them is equal to 0, and others dont, still render the element

Comment: Could you add `console.log(item)` before `return <DestinationItem ...>` to get an example of one that gets rendered which shouldn't?

Comment: i'll add to the description, aspen, for example, has all 0

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I'm not fully sure, but I try not to use `if` statements in the DOM. Try this style of conditional instead:

```
    <div className={styles.list}>
  {locations.map((item) => 
        (item.cars != 0 || item.yachts != 0 || item.villas != 0) && (
            <DestinationItem
              id={item.id}
              key={item.id}
              image={Image[item.id]}
              name={item.name}
              subtitle={item.description}
              description={DESTINATIONS_DESCRIPTION[item.id]}
            />)
  })
</div>;
```

The `&&` operator acts as your if statement. And this way, you don't even need to include `{}`s in your map function. Also, don't forget to add a unique key to any mapped elements!